# How to use .find to look through multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So on click of the div it is supposed to get the value of its data-type attribute, and look for that in the array. If it isn't in one place it looks at the next object in the array. When it finds it, it brings back the whole object. The issue is I can get it to look through one array with .find. How about multiple? Thanks.

```js
var task1 = { name : "test", test: "nope1" }
var task2 = { name : "test", test: "nope2" }
var task3 = { name : "test", test: "nope3" }
var task4 = { name : "test", test: "nope4" }

var A = [task1, task2];
var B = [task3, task4];

$('.test').click(function(){
  var record = $(this).data('type');
  var found = /*A,*/B.find(function(t) {
    return t.test === record;
  });
  console.log(found);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test" data-type="nope4">
  Nope.
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can concatenate multiple arrays using the function **[`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)** into one and then execute the function **[`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)**.

*This example will find the task `test: nope3`.*

```js
var task1 = {
  name: "test",
  test: "nope1"
}
var task2 = {
  name: "test",
  test: "nope2"
}
var task3 = {
  name: "test",
  test: "nope3"
}
var task4 = {
  name: "test",
  test: "nope4"
}

var A = [task1, task2];
var B = [task3, task4];

$('.test').click(function() {
  var record = $(this).data('type');
  var found = A.concat(B).find(function(t) {
    return t.test === record;
  });
  
  console.log(found);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='test' data-type='nope3'>Click me!</button>
```

Comment: Can you keep concatting? Example:  A.concat(B).concat(C).concat(D)

Comment: @Will yes, you can do that!

Comment: @Will you can do this as well: `A.concat(B, C, D) `